# Aceder a um site de um servidor que está na mesma LAN (XAMPP)

Tags: web-service, servidor, xampp

Olá a todos!

Tenho dois computadores:

- Windows 7;
- Windows Server 2012.

O meu site está no xampp do windows server 2012, e eu quero aceder a ele através do windows 7.

Já tentei pesquisar no browser pelo IP, pelo nome do Windows Server 2012, e também tentei pesquisar pelo NomeDoWindowsServer.NomeDaEmpresa.com mas o erro é sempre o mesmo:

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Gostava de saber o que preciso de configurar no Xampp, ou até mesmo no Windows Server 2012 para conseguir resolver este erro.
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O servidor tem de estar configurado para aceitar conexões externas dentro rede, na porta 80, que por default é a que o XAMPP usa, mas pode ser diferente, tens de confirmar no XAMPP.

Comment: @Leite Como é que eu configuro o xampp para aceitar conexões externas?

Comment: Procura o `httpd.conf` do xampp, tem de haver uma linha que diga algo `Listen 80`, acho que o xampp já deve estar configurado para aceitar os pedidos, mas podes confirmar. O servidor pode ter firewall? Control Panel > Firewall, se tiver e estiver activa, tens de configurar ai excepções para a porta 80.

Comment: @Leite Sim aparece Listen 80, e em relação à firewall, eu pus turn off, do que achas que poderá ser?

Comment: Deve ter algo tipo `ServerName localhost:80` no **httpd.conf**, que valor tens? Se for `localhost`, muda para ser o IP do servidor, e.g. `ServerName 192.168.10.10:80`

Comment: OBRIGADO!!!! CONSEGUI RESOLVER!! Andei a tentar resolver isto à umas 2 semans, funcionou muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leite

> Deve ter algo tipo `ServerName localhost:80` no httpd.conf, que valor tens? Se for `localhost`, muda para ser o IP do servidor, e.g. `ServerName 192.168.10.10:80`